# Error while upload an image in java through ajax and display it on front-end, help me out

Tags: java, ajax, post, servlets, jquery-file-upload

Am trying upload an image to servlet in java using jQuery ajax. the file is uploading correctly, and the problem raised when am returning the same path to response to display the image on the screen.

**servlet code:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String returnPath = "";
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    try {
        List<FileItem> list = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);
        for(FileItem items : list) {
            String fileName = new File(items.getName()).getName();
            String filePath = request.getContextPath()+File.separator+"images";
            if(!new File(filePath).exists()) {
                new File(filePath).mkdir();
            }
            System.out.println(System.getProperty("catalina.home"));
            String storeFile = filePath+File.separator+fileName;
            returnPath = storeFile;
            if(new File(storeFile).exists()) {
                System.out.println("already exists");
            }else if(!new File(storeFile).exists()) {
                items.write(new File(storeFile));
                System.out.println("uploaded");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().write(returnPath);
}
```

**html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submitBtn').click(function(){
            var form = $('#myForm')[0];
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("simpleFile",document.getElementById('file').files[0])
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                enctype:'multipart/form-data',
                url:'upload',
                data:formData,
                processData:false,
                contentType :false,
                cache:false,
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    alert(response);
                    $('#myImg').attr('src',response);
                },
                error:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

**Console**

```
Tulips.jpg:1 GET http://localhost:8080/ImageUploadAjax/images/Tulips.jpg 404 ()
```